# Need to drop tables older than three days

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am very new to the development of Oracle PL/SQL db apps...I have a customer requirement of which we have created an ETL for them that drops that previous days table. That table is created by using a synonym and it take a time stamp to create the table as for example: TEST_TEST_todaysdate

Now they would like to alter the ETL and do not want to drop the previous days table, rather they would like to keep three days worth of data and on the fourth day...the procedure should delete the last days as a loop so that the table retains the last three days! I hope you guys get me but its like this - from Monday to Wednesday, on Thursday then delete Monday, On Friday then delete Tuesday, etc.

Here is a code snippet:

```
   -- check &&1..&&3._&&2
   select count(*)
   into v_exist
   from all_tables
   where owner = upper('&&1')
   and   table_name = upper('&&3._&&2');

   if v_exist > 0 then
      for r in (select owner,table_name
                from all_tables
                where  owner = upper('&&1')
                and    table_name like upper('&&3%')  --- exclude MASTER_* tables
                and    table_name <>  upper('&&3')    --- just for precaution
```

This is my code:

```
and    table_name = start_day DATE as ((SELECT extract(hour from current_timestamp)) - 4 FROM dual
  --and    table name =' || previous_days_table ||' -- saving previous days table
                and    table_name < upper('&&3._&&2')) loop
          v_sql := 'DROP TABLE ' || r.owner || '.' || r.table_name || ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE';
          dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
          execute immediate v_sql;
      end loop;
   end if;
EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
                RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: You may want to look into [partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/partition.htm#g471747).

Comment: Whoever is generating the requirement is unquestionably a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this; the first is based on your own date stamp; the second on the date the table was created.

Assuming your datestamp was in the format YYYYMMDD I would do something like this:

```
begin

   for xx in ( select owner, table_name
                 from all_tables
                where regexp_like(table_name, 'TEST_TEST_[[:digit:]]{8}')
                  and to_date(substr(table_name, -8), 'yyyymmdd') < trunc(sysdate) - 4
                  and owner = 'THE_OWNER'
                      ) loop

      execute immediate 'drop table ' ||
                          xx.owner || '.' ||
                          xx.table_name ||
                          ' purge';

   end loop;

end;
/
```

Essentially, it's all about getting your SQL statement correct so that you only have contained in there the tables that you want to drop.

Alternatively, you can use the date that the object was created from ALL_OBJECTS, making your SQL statement something like this:

```
select owner, object_name
  from all_objects
 where object_type = 'TABLE'
   and regexp_like(object_name, 'TEST_TEST_[[:digit:]]{8}')
   and trunc(created) < trunc(sysdate) - 4
   and owner = 'THE_OWNER'
       ;
```

Please note that doing this, especially with the PURGE keyword is inherently dangerous. It might be better, if possible, to alter your ETL to load into a single table with the date as a column and then delete from that table any data you no longer need. This would also remove the need for the dynamic creating and dropping of tables.

Comment: One comment - remember to run PURGE RECYCLEBIN at the end of the procedure - on oracle 11g drop table command by default doesn't remove the table and free space on disk, but places the table into recycle bin.

Comment: ups, I am sorry @Ben, i didn't see it, it is hidden behind margin.

Comment: Edited the response so all clauses in the `drop table` are visible.

Comment: Running this code as a privileged user and you've just hosed your database. The entire approach of dropping tables instead of managing data sets seems doomed, so I say go for it little doodle. At least change to user_objects...

Comment: If you run this as a privileged user using USER_TABLES then you've probably just hosed your database @CleverIdeaWidgetry. I did add that it's inherently dangerous and provide a better / safer idea at the same time. It is restricted to tables with dates so it could be a lot worse :).

Comment: It's also worth noting that this pattern isn't uncommon in ETL, when you load many multi-gigabyte files daily this is often the easiest way...

Comment: @Ben - Touché...I suppose. However if your privileged user to run ETL maintenance scripts is SYS or SYSTEM then I guess nothing you do or don't do really matters. And just because something isn't uncommon doesn't make it any better an idea. I've never seen it used and I'm better off for it.